# Why Rubidium-87 instead of Rubidium-85 for Atomic Clocks?

Tags: atomic-clocks, hyperfine-structure

The traditional Rubidium isotope of choice for atomic clocks is Rubidium-87, although I have found papers describing clocks built around Rubidium-85. I cannot readily find any references for why 87 is preferred in clocks.

Rubidium-85 is the naturally more common isotope (72% vs 28% for Rubidium-87) and is radioactively stable. Meanwhile, Rubidium-87 is weakly radioactive with a half life around 50 billion years, though I imagine this fact is not of much importance.

Meanwhile, the hyperfine transition frequency used in Rubidium-87 is around 6.8 GHz while that for Rubidium-85 is around 3.0 GHz. So for a given quality factor, it would appear the clock employing the 3.0 GHz transition would have a smaller linewidth than a 6.8 GHz clock, leading to higher stability.

So I haven't found a compelling reason for why Rubidium-87 would dominate the atomic clock scene. I would appreciate an identification of what I'm missing here.

Comment: Contrary to your last point, one typically chooses a clock with as fast an oscillation as possible, because it gives higher time resolution and thus higher stability. This is why Rb and Cs clocks have been overtaken by optical clocks (100s of THz range), and why proposals exist to move to nuclear transitions that are at even higher frequencies.

Comment: @Rococo I have seen this claim in multiple locations, however I have some trouble with it. First, as a counterexample, Hydrogen clocks achieve lower Allan deviation (roughly two orders of magnitude) at 1.42 GHz compared to Cesium clocks at 9.20 GHz, which seems to contradict your claim. Now I agree that, given a fixed resonance linewidth, a higher frequency would yield a more stable clock. This is because if I wanted to generate, say, a 10 MHz reference output from the clock, I would need to divide the hyperfine transition frequency by some factor, which in turn scales down ...

Comment: the clock's frequency drift by the same factor. So using a higher hyperfine transition frequency would result in a higher division factor, and thus higher stability. However, the linewidth for the different atoms is certainly not the same. So there is an additional factor in choosing which frequency (and hence, which atom) to use in a clock. A better metric than just the frequency would be the ratio of center frequency to linewidth, perhaps, which is essentially the quality factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People always ask me "Why rubidium?" and it was fun to finally get to look into the answer. We use ${}^{87}$Rb in my lab.

And I think it's worth first asking the question in exactly that form: why rubidium?

I think the answer is largely historical.

Rubidium actually got laser cooled a little later than some other common atoms, but then it was realized that CD drives had diodes that worked at 780 nm, the wavelength needed for laser cooling Rb. This brought laser cooling into the reach of a lot of labs that didn't necessarily have huge amounts of funding for the early laser systems.

There are a couple of other good reasons for rubidium to have been historically chosen, as well. You have to understand that the holy grail of early atomic physics was getting a BEC, a Bose-Einstein condensate. And all thoughts were geared in that direction. So when they found an atom with a positive background scattering length, whose atomic cross sections also made evaporative cooling meaningfully useful, they believed they found "God's atom" (this quote might come from Eric Cornell).

***Edited to add: "historical reasons" might not seem like the best justification (which it isn't), but remember that, even now, a good number of PIs and faculty in atomic physics were grad students, postdocs, and early-career faculty when laser cooling was still new, so these historical reasons came at a time that shaped their thinking for the rest of their careers, and therefore the design of their experiments, the ones producing papers today. My PI still talks about the old dye laser systems sometimes.

As a note, ${}^{85}$Rb actually has a *negative* background scattering length, which makes BECs unstable unless you use a Feshbach resonance at a fairly large magnetic field to make it positive. This puts it at a historical disadvantage.

But there's actually a better reason not to use 85 in your specific application, atomic clocks. It's simple and already stated here on the thread: its ground-state hyperfine frequency of 3-ish GHz is *smaller* than 87's splitting of 6.8 GHz.

This is why cesium, at over 9 GHz, is still the world's standard, and why the new strontium optical lattice clocks (which work at 429 THz) are the world-record holders.

When you think about atomic clocks, the absolute first question you have to ask is "How fast *can* it go?" The questions of quality and stability are engineering questions; the fundamental oscillation frequency is something you can never get around except by changing the basic setup.

You want to be reaching for stability that matches the fastest oscillation you can get, *not* settling for a slower clock that you can get really stable.

The related statement I should make is a different way of thinking about the quality factor. This quantity is defined as $Q=\nu_0/\Delta\nu$. That is, for a given quality factor, a higher resonance frequency requires a *higher* linewidth. And since $Q$ is generally in the denominator of the instability, higher $Q$, means lower instability. This means higher resonance frequency gives lower instability... if you can keep the linewidth down.

Now, two isotopes of rubidium don't differ too much in the basic atomic properties. In particular the *fundamental* stability limit, the linewidth of the excited state, will always vary very little between isotopes. I can't seem to find a comparison of the atomic linewidths of the transitions actually used in rubidium clocks (the two-photon transitions or the actual "clock transition"), so as an example, the 5P to 5S transition, the linewidth is 6.066 MHz in ${}^{85}$Rb and 6.059 MHz in ${}^{87}$Rb. Getting down to that fundamental limit is just engineering, and any laser and vacuum systems that will work with 85 will work with 87 since they only really vary by being isotopes. (If anything, 87 I think is easier to trap due to lower vaporizing temperature, but don't quote me on that.) So the linewidth can in fact be kept about constant between the two isotopes.

So if you're going for rubidium, you want the faster oscillator with the same linewidth: ${}^{87}$Rb is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding your last point, I got the relation for Q correct in my original post. I said that for a given Q, a lower transition frequency would have a lower line width -- the same conclusion you reach in your answer, except vice versa. Your conclusion makes perfect sense to me if line width can be held constant as transition frequency is increased. I don't know if this is actually the case. I brought up the example of the hydrogen atomic clock in one of my comments as a counter example, as it has both a lower frequency and better stability.

Comment: I think dismissing the quality factor and stability as engineering questions is the wrong way to go about things, since at the end of the day, atomic clocks are design and used to keep highly stable time. And what pays the bills, so to speak, is the ultimate stability. So I guess if we assume that the choice of Rb-87 over Rb-85 for clock use was indeed related to Q and frequency, we would need to confirm that the achievable Q for Rb-87 is greater than 3.0/6.8 = 0.44 times that of Rb-85. At least historically, as more recent advanced may have changed the game.

Comment: @LetterSized I've edited my answer to reflect some of these points, and to say the following. First, there are fundamental limits you want to keep track of. For 85 vs 87, 87 is the faster oscillator fundamentally, *and* its base atomic linewidths will be very similar to 85 because they're just two isotopes of the same atom, so their electronic properties won't differ much. This includes all the transition frequencies needed to cool and manipulate the atom, so any laser system that works on 85 will work on 87 with very similar technical specs.

Comment: @LetterSized In this sense it is possible - indeed trivial - to keep the linewidth the same but increase the transition frequency, thereby attaining a better $Q$ and lower stability.

Comment: I think that clears up all my concerns, thanks!

Comment: Nice answer. From what I understand, the measured linewidths in microwave clock transitions are dominated by non-fundamental effects like collisional broadening, rather than the fundamental linewidth (which is essentially zero). While I haven't found a definitive statement, I think it is reasonable to expect that for two isotopes, as you said, these broadening mechanisms end up having similar effects so that the higher frequency will usually win out.

Comment: There's a nice Physics Today article that touches on some of this (paywalled, sorry):https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.2812121

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth (US patent [US6320472B1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6320472B1/en)):

> The resonance cell, containing the ensemble of alkali atoms, is placed
> inside a microwave cavity tuned to the transition between which the
> population inversion has been created. The light transmitted is
> detected with the help of a photodetector, as shown in FIG. 1. It is
> to be noted that, upon optical pumping, the cell becomes transparent
> to the incident radiation since atoms are pumped out of the absorbing
> level, F=1. Microwave energy is fed to the cavity and its effect on
> the atoms, when tuned to the hyperfine frequency, is to alter the
> population of the two levels of the ground state and, consequently,
> the optical transmission of the ensemble. The ground state hyperfine
> resonance signal is thus detected on the transmitted light and is used
> to lock the frequency of the microwave source used to feed the cavity.
> The resulting device is a system whose frequency is locked to an
> atomic resonance.

> Although this approach has achieved substantial
> success, it has, nonetheless, several disadvantages. **In particular,**
> **the need for a microwave cavity limits availability of reduction in**
> **the dimensions of the device. This limitation has been a main factor**
> **in the selection of rubidium 87 (hyperfine frequency=6.8 GHz) over**
> **rubidium 85 (hyperfine frequency=3.0 GHz), the cavity size required**
> **being larger for rubidium 85 than for rubidium 87.**

Comment: Relatedly, it's easier to measure very brief periods when the frequency is higher.

Comment: Interesting. So if size is the only factor in choosing 87 over 85, then for clocks using Coherent Population Trapping (CPT), for which a microwave cavity is not needed, should not show any preference towards 87 over 85. Except perhaps because "that's how it's always been done." The factor of upmost importance is obtaining a sample of Rubidium that is as pure as possible, whether is be the 85 or the isotope.

Comment: @LetterSized : the patent does not say this is the only factor, but see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228401629_CPT_Atomic_Clock_based_on_Rubidium_85 :"We have fabricated and tested a compact physics package based on CPT in the rubidium 85 isotope. The main parts of the package include a commercial available 795nm VCSEL and a miniature glass blown vapour cell. In contrast to previous work that used pure (or enriched) rubidium 87, we fill the vapour cell with natural rubidium. This solution is simpler and more cost effective."

Comment: @akhmeteli This reference seems to support that idea that the main reason why 87 is used in CPT clocks is because clocks have always been made with 87. Which of course doesn't answer why 87 was used in the first place. I find it mildly hard to believe that microwave cavity size was the _only_ factor in choosing 87 though.

Comment: @LetterSized It clearly states, in the bold text, that the size of the required cavity was the prime consideration in the original selection. Why do you find that hard to believe? It's exactly the kind of criterion that a practical physicist uses.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to lookup these two points that may offer a plausible explanation -

From the [Wikipedia entry for Rubidium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubidium) -

> In 1995, rubidium-87 was used to produce a Bose–Einstein condensate,
> for which the discoverers, Eric Allin Cornell, Carl Edwin Wieman and
> Wolfgang Ketterle, won the 2001 Nobel Prize in Physics.

And also from the [Wikipedia entry on Bose–Einstein_condensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate) -

> In condensed matter physics, a Bose–Einstein condensate (BEC) is a
> state of matter that is typically formed when a gas of bosons at very
> low densities is cooled to temperatures very close to absolute zero
> (−273.15 °C or −459.67 °F). Under such conditions, a large fraction of
> bosons occupy the lowest quantum state, at which point microscopic
> quantum mechanical phenomena, **particularly wavefunction interference,
> become apparent macroscopically**. A BEC is formed by cooling a gas
> of extremely low density (about 100,000 times less dense than normal
> air) to ultra-low temperatures.

Perhaps these two points above can offer the explanation you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates directly to atomic clocks though. 1995 is well after the first rubidium atomic clocks were made, and this doesn't explain how Rb-87 compares to Rb-85.